# Get number of relationships for each relationship type and label in Neo4j

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I have this query:

```
MATCH (a:Label_A)-[r]-(b:Label_B)
RETURN type(r) AS Relationship_Type, COUNT(*) AS Count
```

Which yields a table with headers *Relationship_Type* and *Count* and the count for each type of relationship. 
I would like to  expand this table to have the counts for each type of label, so not just between `Label_A` and `Label_B`, but also `Label_A` and `Label_C`, `Label_B` and `Label_C`, etc. With corresponding columns such as `Count_Label_B_Label_C` for each possible combination. 
How could that be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query will go through all relationships in the database, enumerate all labels on start and end node and then count how often these pairs appear:

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)
UNWIND labels(a) AS Label_Start
UNWIND labels(b) AS Label_End
RETURN
  type(r) AS RelationshipType,
  Label_Start,
  Label_End,
  count([Label_Start, Label_End]) AS Count
```

Answer (score 1):

Like with SQL the columns in Cypher are fixed (except if you use RETURN *), so it is hard to achieve a column per label-pair without knowing the possible label-pairs when you write the query.

There are other ways to solve it though. One is to have one row for each relationship type and label pair. Another one is to return a map for the different label pairs.

Another thing that we need to consider is that nodes can have many labels (and can even be without label).

If you have access to APOC Core you could do like this to get one row per node-pair-type:

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)
WITH DISTINCT apoc.text.join(labels(a), '_')+'_'+apoc.text.join(labels(b), '_') AS Labels,r
RETURN type(r) AS Relationship_Type, Labels, COUNT(*) AS Count
```

To get the result as a map you could do:

```
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)
WITH DISTINCT apoc.text.join(labels(a), '_')+'_'+apoc.text.join(labels(b), '_') AS Labels,r
WITH type(r) AS Relationship_Type, Labels, COUNT(*) AS c
RETURN Relationship_Type, apoc.map.fromPairs(collect([Labels, c])) AS Count
```